# Ending a connection pool in mysql-connector-python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I have a connection pool that I create using mysql-connector-python:

```
dbconfig = {
        "database": db,
        "user":     "user"
}    
cnxpool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name = appname,
                                  pool_size = 5,
                                  **dbconfig)
```

In the [mysql-connector API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnectionpool.html), there doesn't appear to be a method for ending a connection pool.  Is there a way to end a connection pool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html

You can just call the close()  method of the pool

EDIT :

As commented, this will not close the pool, it will only return the connection to the pool.

I looked at this source code https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/master/lib/mysql/connector/pooling.py

And it looks like the only method that will do it is _remove_connections but it is intended for testing.

Comment: According to the docs, that method is for returning an individual connection to the pool.  It doesn't look like that method can be called on a pool.  Am I wrong?

Comment: It says "mostly for testing", but looks like it will accomplish what I want.  I will test it to make sure.

Comment: The GitHub link is dead. [Here's a live one.](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/trunk/mysql-connector-python/lib/mysql/connector/pooling.py)