# Closing MYSQL connection pool properly in Python

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, connection-pooling

I am using mysql.connector.pooling to create a pooled group of connections to use in my multithreaded/multiprocessing based application. The following code creates the records as expect but I notice at the end of the run that the /var/log/mysql/error.log has an entry for each thread which is "2022-04-02T10:14:08.264395Z 2513 [Note] Aborted connection 2513 to db: 'my_db' user: 'my_user' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)"

After reading a number of articles I believe that the close I call in my thread to close a pooled connection is only returning the connection back to the pool and so the whole pool/connections are not actually closed properly.

Not sure how to close the pool properly.  Looking for help.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.pooling import MySQLConnectionPool
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from mysql.connector.errors import Error
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import datetime
from timeit import default_timer as timer

my_db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                                user="my_user",
                                password="my_password",
                                database="my_db")


def init_pools():
    global pool_for_db
    try:
        db_config = {
            "host": "localhost",
            "user": "my_user",
            "password": "my_password",
            "database": "my_db"
        }
        pool_for_my_db = MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name="pool_for_my_db",
                                               pool_size=1,
                                               **db_config)

    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print("Invalid password on main database")
            exit(0)
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print("Database not initialised")
            exit(0)


def sql_select(item):
    connection = pool_for_my_db.get_connection()
    my_db_cursor = connection.cursor()
    my_db_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM connection_test WHERE row2 = " + str(item))
    connection.close()


def clear_table():
    my_db_cursor = my_db.cursor()
    sql_statement = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM connection_test"
    my_db_cursor.execute(sql_statement)
    count = my_db_cursor.fetchone()
    print('Count is', count)

    my_db_cursor = my_db.cursor()
    sql_statement = "DELETE FROM connection_test"
    my_db_cursor.execute(sql_statement)
    my_db.commit()
    print(my_db_cursor.rowcount, "record(s) deleted")


def table_insert(item):
    try:
        connection = pool_for_my_db.get_connection()
        my_db_cursor = connection.cursor()

        sql_statement = "INSERT INTO connection_test (row1, row2, row3) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
        values = (pool_for_my_db.pool_name, item, datetime.datetime.now())
        my_db_cursor.execute(sql_statement, values)
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        print("Error code:", e.errno)  # error number
        print("SQLSTATE value:", e.sqlstate)  # SQLSTATE value
        print("Error message:", e.msg)  # error message
        print("Error:", e)  # errno, sqlstate, msg values
        s = str(e)
        print("Error:", s)

my_list = [*range(0, 100000)]
mp.set_start_method("fork")
#
# clear_table()
#
# start = timer()
# print('Starting 16 thread run')
# with mp.Pool(16, initializer=init_pools) as p:
#     p.map(table_insert, my_list)
# p.close()
# p.join()
# end = timer()
# print("Time for 16 run", end-start)

# clear_table()

# start = timer()
# print('Starting 32 thread run')
# with mp.Pool(32, initializer=init_pools) as p:
#     p.map(table_insert, my_list)
# p.close()
# p.join()
# end = timer()
# print("Time for 32 run", end-start)
#
# clear_table()
#
# start = timer()
# print('Starting 48 thread run')
# with mp.Pool(48, initializer=init_pools) as p:
#     p.map(table_insert, my_list)
# p.close()
# p.join()
# end = timer()
# print("Time for 48 run", end-start)
#
clear_table()

start = timer()
print('Starting 64 thread run')
with mp.Pool(64, initializer=init_pools) as p:
    p.map(table_insert, my_list)
p.close()
p.join()
end = timer()
print("Time for 64 run", end-start)
```

Comment: Similar (but no solutions) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47109402/close-pooled-connections-to-mysql-from-mysql-connector-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421447/ending-a-connection-pool-in-mysql-connector-python).

Comment: If your application runs from start to finish, rather than being persistent, why do you need a connection pool? Couldn't each thread open and close its own connection?